# How to add locally downloaded archetypes in Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

I have downloaded Maven archetypes in Eclipse manually. I tried to add them by using the Remote Catalogue, but our company firewall restricts it. So, I have downloaded the archetypes (jars) from our company's local repository.

Can someone please suggest how to add the locally downloaded archetype jars into eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the artifact into your local repository (`install:install-file`) and then update the catalogue by using `archetype:update-local-catalog`.